# Twilio - Setup Programmable Voice using VOIP IP Phone, Yealink/Polycom

Tags: twilio, voip

I am fairly new to Twilio and VOIP hard phones.

I have successfully setup Twilio Programmable Wireless to make and receive calls and text with iPhone but I cannot get Voice to work on an IP desk phone.

Can someone provide a guide/writeup on how to set up **Twilio's Programmable Voice** to work with an IP phone from Yealink or Polycom?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below blog, it will walk you through the various steps for registering a SIP phone directly to Twilio to make and receive calls.

[Registering a SIP Phone Directly to Twilio (and so much more...)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound)